# Get classes with at least two same access specifiers with ASTMatcher

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-query

I need to catch cases in C++ code when there are two or more similar access specifiers in the class.
Let's say there are two classes

```
class A{
public:
    int b;
public:
    int a;
}

class B{
public:
    int a;
}
```

How to match class A (because it has two 'public's) but not class B with ASTMatcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This matcher grabs the 'public' declaration:

```
accessSpecDecl(
  isPublic(),
  hasAncestor(cxxRecordDecl().bind("crd"))).bind("asd")
```

In the callback class, you can track the number of hits the matcher gets for a given struct declaration, for example with a `std::map<string,int>`:

```
struct report_public : public MatchCallback{
  using map_t = std::map<string,int>;
  using map_it = map_t::iterator;

  map_t count;

  void run(MatchResult const & result){
    AccessSpecDecl const * asd = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<AccessSpecDecl>("asd");
    CXXRecordDecl const * crd = result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXRecordDecl>("crd");
    if(asd && crd){
      string const struct_name = crd->getNameAsString();
      map_it it = count.find(struct_name);
      if(it != count.end()) count[struct_name]++;
      else count[struct_name] = 1;
    }
    else { /* error handling */}
    return;
  } // run
}; // report_public
```

Comment: Ok, so as I understand, it is not possible to achieve that with just Matcher?

Comment: I don't know how to say 'greater than one of these nodes'.